# Manage rel attribute in CKEditor Link dialog

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor, wysiwyg

I need to allow my users to manage the rel attribute when inserting a link in CKEditor.
I need to add in the CKeditor link dialog box a dropdown (or a textbox) allowing users to insert the rel value.
How this can be done?